# How do I get Hebrew voice input and output with wit.ai on Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, hebrew, wit.ai, talkback

Wit.ai supports Hebrew [as seen here](https://wit.ai/faq). I suppose that means Hebrew text.

But how do I get it to understand my speech and to output in Talkback (the equivalent to IOS Voiceover) on Android. Do I have to install some external Hebrew speech reco or text-to-speech like Dragon, like they claimed in the past on [Negishut (Hebrew accessibility website)](http://www.nagish.org.il/?page_id=2934)?

Or does the Google Speech already understand my Hebrew speech and can translate it into Hebrew text? And does the Talkback already support Hebrew?

Is there anything else I need to do to get this working on an advanced version of Android and smartphone (say Samsung Galaxy S)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.codefactory.vocalizertts

After installing the application, you must purchase the preferred voice - for this matter Hebrew.
Next you need to go to the "Text to Speech" settings and choose Vocalizer as a speech engine

Comment: So @Mani ? your answer is that I need a paid Hebrew vocalizer. And this is an example. right? Or is it that the only solution for Hebrew. And are you saying I don't need to do anything for the input because I can use Google Voice Input? – pashute 10 hours ago

Comment: Definelty there could be other alternatives but this one I took from http://www.nagish.org.il/?page_id=2934